# Angular 13: Property 'product' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular

Estou com problema em um component em uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo para aprender angular.

**product.model.ts:**

```
export interface Product {
    id?: number
    name: string
    price: number
}
```

**product.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from './product.model';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  baseUrl =  'http://localhost:3001/produtos';

  constructor(
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  showMessage(msg: string): void{
    this.snackBar.open(msg, 'x',{
      duration: 3000,
      horizontalPosition: 'right',
      verticalPosition: 'top'
    })
  }

  create(product: Product): Observable<Product>{
    return this.http.post<Product>(this.baseUrl, product)
  }

  read(): Observable<Product[]>{
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.baseUrl)
  }

  readById(id: number): Observable<Product>{
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Product>(url);
  }



  update(product: Product): Observable<Product>{
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${product.id}`
    return this.http.put<Product>(url, product)
  }
}
```

***Erro***

**product-update.component.ts**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Product } from "../product.model";
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-update',
  templateUrl: './product-update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-update.component.css']
})
export class ProductUpdateComponent implements OnInit {

 product: Product;

  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService, 
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //const id: number = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    const id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!, 10);
    this.productService.readById(id).subscribe(product =>{
     this.product = product
    });
  }

  updateProduct(): void{

  }

  cancel(): void{
    this.router.navigate(['/products'])
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido:

Faltou iniciar a struct na class

```
export class ProductUpdateComponent implements OnInit {

 product: Product = {
  id: 0,
  name: '',
  price: 0
 }
```